# Elasticsearch - Substring query with wildcards and reserved characters

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a question very similar to Hyphen search with wildcard '*' and normal serach1.

My requirement is I want to be able to do a substring query, in which that substring can contain special characters. For example, I want to be able to query on a list of fields, and in that query I can contain a special character and look for fields that contain that special character as well.

For example:
query: e&S search should pull back a result of joe&sally for example.

Configuration:
I’m using the whitespace analyzer, wrapping all words with wildcards, and escaping all reserved characters. What else can I do?

Thanks,
Matthew